Edge Forced color and high contrast warning
I am constantly seeing this warning in my Microsoft Edge Console.
"[Deprecation] -ms-high-constrast is in the process of being deprecated. Please see  for tips on updating to the new Forced Colors Mode standard."
I have disabled 'edge://flags/#edge-ms-high-contrast', still the annoying warning is not going. I am not using any high contrast media query style in my project. I checked my whole file and there is no style such as -ms-high-contrast-adjust or -ms-high-contrast in my project. I generally use tailwind CSS and React for my projects.

Sometimes it's not from your code but from the libraries you use. You can refer to this similar thread. It's integrated in the component so you won't be able to change that.
I suggest that you use the latest versions of libraries for your projects to see if the warning disappears. If it still exists and you can find from which library, you can provide feedback to them.

Thank you for suggesting. Following your comment, I searched hard for the source of the code. In my case, it was the Microsoft Editor extension.

I found the source of the problem. If anyone faces similar issues, I suggest seeing the source of the code ('sources' tab in your console) that is creating the problem and seeing what extension or library is injecting the code. In my case, it was actually Microsoft Editor Extension. I turned it off, and the warning was gone!
